# InetAddress.getAllByName() only receives IPv4 addresses with java.net.preferIPv6Addresses

Tags: java, android, ios, ipv6, oracle-maf

#### tl;dr

`InetAddress.getAllByName()` only receives a list of IPv4 addresses, even when `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` is set to true, on a NAT64 network, on iOS devices. The same code works as expected on an android connected to the same network.

This means in an ipv6 only network (as required by the Apple store) any application attempting to make a HttpURLConnection will fail, and will be rejected by Apple.

#### Original Post

I am creating an app for iOS in Java, I connect to the server using `HttpsURLConnection` and everything works fine until I test on an NAT64 network. The app is being rejected by the Apple review team, and so I am testing locally using an NAT64 network.

To create my NAT64 network I follow these steps: [Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16)

#### Sample Code:

```
HttpsURLConnection testConn = null;
try {
    URL testUrl = new URL("https://google.com");
    testConn = (HttpsURLConnection) testUrl.openConnection();
    testConn.connect();     
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    if(testConn != null){
        testConn.disconnect();              
    }           
}
```

This code fails with a `java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable` while on my NAT64 network.

I have tried changing system properties:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "false");
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");
```

I have also tried setting the website to something other than our servers (as seen in the test code with google.com). I have also sniffed the packets from the wi-fi connection using wireshark, and the only traffic is a DNS request for google.com which does not seem to fail. Finally I have also tried moving back to a `HttpURLConnection` in case the problems was to do with HTTPS.

Also worth noting is safari on the test iPhone can reach all of our servers and domains without trouble, and the device seems to have a stable and functional internet connection otherwise. The app also fails on my android device when it is connected to the same NAT64 network.

#### Edit:

Setting `System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");` solves the problem on android, so now the issue is isolated to my iPhone5 on the NAT64 network. My best guess at this stage is that the property is being set by another class and is being ignored. I have tried setting the property in a static initializer block at the top of my class, to no avail.

#### Edit 2:

I used `System.getProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses")` and it returns `true` on the iPhone5 so it's definitely being set, leaving me stumped again.

#### Edit 3:

I dug into `HttpsURLConnection` and it implements a `PlainSocketImpl` class to handle its connection, which uses an `InetAddress`. I decided to test an `InetAddress` and when I call `InetAddress.getByName("google.com")` on the iPhone I get an ipv4 address, while on the android it is returning an ipv6 address. It seems that the property `java.net.preferIPv6Addresses` is being ignored on iOS. I have tried updating the JDK to the latest version but this has not helped.

I have also just tried `InetAddress.getAllByName("www.google.com")` and it only return IPv4 addresses on the iPhone. I would say this is clearly a DNS problem, but then why is it not an issue on an android connected to the same network?

So I now know what the issue is, yet have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a way to run Java on iOS. What is the Java runtime used here?

Comment: I'm using oracle's mobile application framework. During configuration you provide it with a JRE. I'm hazy on how it actually implements this on the device, I can only assume it bundles the JVM within a native wrapper. This is why one of my steps was to make sure I had the latest JDK on my build device.

Comment: Okay, are you using [MAF 2.3.2 or later?](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/oracle_maf_2_3_2) It appears that's a requirement, and you shouldn't have to do anything new. Also explore the `NetworkInterface` class, and log what interfaces are available to the JVM. You can also explicitly create an IPv6 address (bypassing DNS) and see if you can open a socket with it.

Comment: I am using 2.3.2 but not 2.4. There's some issue with the current version of MAF for Eclipse (OEPE) and it's not updating to the latest MAF, I've gone about notifying the right people. I will poke about in `NetworkInterface`. The problem with not specifying a URL, is that I require HTTPS, so with an explicit IP it can no longer find the certificate in caserts. That's a whole other kettle of fish I don't want to get into if I can avoid it. Thanks for the help @erickson

Comment: Right, I just meant as a test, take DNS out of the picture and try to use an IPv6 address and see if it works. Then you can isolate the problem.

Comment: Yep, good point, I'll disable SSL and try it with an explicit IPv6 address. As an aside however, I do think the fact it works on an Android under the same network conditions eliminates DNS as a cause, doesn't it?

Comment: @erickson it turns out because the project was initially created under an older version of MAF, even after updating eclipse etc it was always running in the old MAF environment. I created a new project with the new MAF as the runtime target, and the problem seems to be solved. Would you like to post your version suggestion as a solution so I can accept?

Comment: You should be able to post and accept your own findings as an answer. I think it's useful, and it was not an obvious solution even with my small hint about the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was upgrading my app to run on the latest version of MAF.

Details:

Even though I had updated Eclipse and MAF to the latest version, my application was still using it's original MAF release as the target runtime. I discovered this by viewing my target SDK's and realizing I could not change the runtime verison.

[image: noting the MAF runtime in the SDK settings]

To update I had to create a new project, making sure to set the target runtime to the latest version of MAF. I then migrated my code to this new project, and was able to successfully run my app under an IPv6 only network.

[image: creating a new MAF project and setting the runtime version]

*(at the time of writing MAF 2.3.2 was the latest version available for Eclipse)*

If there is a way to do this without creating a new project, I could not discover it.